# Posting a model with Kendo Grid read action

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a search form to my page that updates the Kendo Grid. How should I send the Ajax call, so the ASP.NET MVC Model Binder be able to work?

This is my Ajax call:

```
var grid = $("#SearchSheetHeads").data('kendoGrid');
var data = $("#SearchSheet").serialize();
grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.url = "@Url.Action("SearchHeaderRead", "Sheet")";
grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.data = data;
grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.dataType = 'json';
grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.contentType = "application/json";
grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.type = "POST";
grid.dataSource.fetch();
```

I've also tried it by `stringify` method and removing `contentType`.

And this is my Action signature:

```
public ActionResult SearchHeaderRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, SearchSheetHeaderViewModel model)
```

And the request looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't test it at the moment, but try something like this:

```
var grid = $("#SearchSheetHeads").data('kendoGrid');
var data = $("#SearchSheet").serialize();
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("SearchHeaderRead", "Sheet")',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { model: data },
    success: function (result) {
        grid.dataSource.data(result.Data);
    }
});
```

`data: { model: data }` is probably the important part for you.

Comment: Yes Vash, the Ajax call works fine. But the `grid.dataSource.data(result)` line gives the error `Object doesn't support property or method 'slice'`. At least when the search result is empty.

Comment: Just did a quick test on one of my own grids and I got it working using `grid.dataSource.data(result.Data)`. Please try that.

Comment: It fixed the error, but it doesn't update the grid! Currently my search doesn't have any result, so it should just clear the grid.

Comment: Maybe I just need to add `grid.dataSource.data([])` before that line.

Comment: That'd work. However, if your controller is returning an empty collection, the `result.Data` should be an empty array and clear the grid, which happens in my test app.

Comment: Is `result.Data` an array? You can just put a `debugger;` statement just before `grid.dataSource.data(result.Data);` to check. Also, ofcourse, ensure that your controller is returning a `DataSourceResult`.

Comment: Oops, I miss typed data with lower case! :D Everything's fine! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the second line as given below and try it out

```
var data = $("#SearchSheetHeads").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();
```

Comment: Thanks Amal, but I'm trying to post my form, not my Grid.

Comment: `SearchSheet` is just a `<form>`, and I don't have any troubles with other Ajax calls this way. I just don't know how to make Kendo Grid do the Ajax call right.